Maximal uniserial modules in local algebras
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra (we can assume that is local and commutative if that helps).

Question 1: What is the maximal vector space dimension of an uniserial $A$-module? Is there a good bound or even a way to get such a maximal uniserial module?

For example for $A=K[x,y]/(x^n,y^n)$ I think one such maximal uniserial module is the regular module of $K[x]/(x^n)$ as an $A$-module when viewing $A$ as the enveloping algebra of $K[x]/(x^n)$.

Question 2: What are the algebras with only finitely many uniserial modules? This is stated as an open problem in the 1994 book by Auslander-Reiten-Smalo. Is there any progress?

